# border-radius for ie7, safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opera

I want to use `border-radius` across all browsers.

It's working on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. However it is not working on Internet Explorer 7, Internet Explorer 8 & Opera.

How this can be done across browsers?

Comment: @atinder Sure, also read the question carefully and see the time when it was asked

Comment: i like to answer old questions.

Comment: @atinder Then why don't you answer it now, if you've something better

Comment: because i feel like this should be a comment and not answer. Learned from you only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83955/discussion-between-tushar-and-atinder).

Comment: mentioned already. and thanks for your guidance. I learned importance of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use PIE.htc for border radius and it works great.

```
border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 20px;
-moz-box-shadow: 20px;
behavior:url(PIE.htc);
```

http://css3pie.com/ <--download and place in the top level of your root folder.